# Coding Investigation, finding bore radius size

Tags: python, math

I'm actually not sure how to pose this question correctly, so let me just tell you what the homework states for me...

"They have bores (that dig the tunnel) that range from 0.25 metres to 8 metres in radius that increment in size by 0.25 metres (0.25, 0.5, 0.75… 7.75, 8).

> At a minimum, your application will:
>
> -Ask the user for the minimum required volume of the tunnel
>
> -Ask the user for the exact length of the tunnel
>
> -Use a loop to determine the bore-size required as well as the exact                   volume that would be produced with that bore.

For extra credit:

> -Tell the user to extend the tunnel if the bore size required is greater than 8m.
>
> -Allow the user to determine the volume of the tunnel with a given bore size and tunnel length
>
> -Allow the user to determine the length of the tunnel with a given bore size and volume (in case the user would prefer to get an exact
>   volume but is flexible with the tunnel length.)
>
> -Provide the user with a list of alternatively shaped prisms (and their dimensions) that could fit the volume and length requirements."

I've tried this but it doesn't look correct;

```
from math import sqrt

a = float(input("What is the minimum volume that is required? (cubic metres): "))

b = float(input("How long do you need the tunnel to be? (metres): "))

pi = 3.14

r = sqrt(a/pi/b)

c = round(r, 2)

print(c)
```

For an input of `a=250` and `b=12` It provides an output of 2.58 when the answer is (supposedly) meant to be 2.75

I'm wondering, how do you round 2.58 to 2.75, and if you have the time, any ideas/help/hints on how to do the extra functionality part?

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question?

Comment: ... for what input values does is your output supposed to be 2.75?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin The minimum volume (in cubic metres) and the length of the tunnel (in metres), also the code after the 2 input values should be the bore radius size

Comment: @KlausD. It would be that if you could point out what's wrong with my code/math, how come the answer is different

Comment: I will repeat and explain my question. You said that the output is 2.58, but it should be 2.75. For that statement to have any meaning for us, we have to know what are the values of the input (`a` and `b`) that should produce that result. So, for what values of `a` and `b` should `c` be equal to 2.75? Is my question clear now?

Comment: @ItamarMuskin Sorry I misunderstood; a = 250 and b = 12

Comment: I think I have a hint. From your question, it says to use a for-loop to find the bore size, and calculate the volume with it. But as the question is posed, there is no need for a for-loop, and the volume is an input. So... perhaps there is only a limited range of possible bore sizes? From the question, it kinda looks like there is. Please look again at the question for that.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin do you think there's something wrong with my mathematical reasoning?

Comment: 1. Your example input should be in the question body, not in comments. Please take the time to visit https://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn more on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: 2. I cannot be sure, but I'm guessing that there is a limited range of possible bore sizes (e.g. only 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3... something like that), and this is why a `for` loop is required. Otherwise, the question - as posed - does not make sense. Also, the "extra credits" part suggest to inform the user if the bore size is >8 - maybe it is the maximum value in this list (e.g. the 2, 2.25, 2.5... goes only up to 8)?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Oh! Okay then... I think that's it; would you mind explaining to me how to do that exactly; however... how to round to 2.75... And I'm so sorry I missed out a part in my copy and pasting I will now add to the original question

Comment: Yes. please format your question in a way that's concise and answerable, and include all relevant information required to answer your question, and I'll answer it.

Comment: I've answered your question. Please, in the future, do the effort of formatting your question to be readable (format code as code, quote as quote, etc), provide required information, and a clear concise example. The https://stackoverflow.com/tour should help a lot. Otherwise, it will be hard to get answers for your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to check which is the first element that is above a certain value, and stop once you've reached it. Generally speaking, it should be something like this:

```
minimum_bore_size = 0.25
bore_size_step = 0.25
maximum_bore_size = 8

required_bore_size = math.sqrt(a / b / math.pi)

if required_bore_size > maximum_bore_size:
    print ('required bore size too big')
    # exit your program somehow

bore_size = minimum_bore_size
while bore_size < maximum_bore_size:
    if bore_size < required_bore_size:
        bore_size = bore_size + bore_size_step
    else:
        volume = math.pow(bore_size,2) * math.pi * b
        print(round(bore_size,2))
        print(volume)
        break
```

Comment: Sorry, thought about `numpy`. edited to `math.pow(bore_size, 2)`

Comment: Also, I'm wondering; in the homework assignment nothing is given about the ending exact volume of the tunnel, however in the assignment it does say that the "Exact volume produced" would be 285.21, and I am very confused; in the code it makes the volume 285.1 (rounded)

Comment: Check your values of `pi` - should you use 3.14 for the assignment, or can you use a much more accurate value like `math.pi`?

Comment: I tried both of them and it didn't work; am getting very frustrated and confused, tried testing this on a calculator too, finding the volume of a cylinder and am getting the same answer so I should be correct but **apparently** not... math.pi is more accurate however... if you still think it's correct then I'll ask my maths teacher if everything in the assignment task sheet is correct and show her the proof

Comment: The next thing you should check is if the both of you rounded to 2 digits in the same places. But that's something you should be able to talk with your teacher about.